# video is not working the video are crashed

Tags: ios

my app is crash  i have see all the tutorial but its crashed all the time.
whats is the problem ?
i use storyboard and i connect the button and thats it .it is crashed

```
- (IBAction)playMove;
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
    player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [player.moviePlayer play];
    player =nil;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the file to play added to the resources ? And what's the error line ?

Comment: i have the but the code are crash

Comment: You can enable the debug mode and place the breakpoint at the beginning of the method, can't you ?